# What are the limitations of USB On-The-Go on Nexus tablets?

Tags: usb-host-mode, usb-on-the-go, samsung-nexus-10

I'm thinking about using USB On-The-Go to extend the rather limited space on the Nexus 10 tablet. I've read about it, but I'm not sure on where exactly the limitations of this approach are. I know that I need a USB OTG cable for it, but I read some conflicting or vague information about other aspects.

- Do I need a specific app? My impression is that I need the Nexus Media Importer, which is a paid app, but is that the only way?
- Which filesystems are supported?
- Can the Nexus 10 deliver enough power through USB to use a portable hard drive, or does it only work with USB flash drives?
- Can I access the external USB drive without restrictions as if it was an SD card, or are there any additional restrictions?

Answer (score 2):

- > Do I need a specific app? My impression is that I need the Nexus Media Importer, which is a paid app, but is that the only way?

  Some apps on Google Play have the ability to read USB OTG data, however an app specifically made for the purpose would be better.
- > Which filesystems are supported?

  Most file systems that Linux supports will be supported.
- > Can the Nexus 10 deliver enough power through USB to use a portable hard drive, or does it only work with USB flash drives?

  No, it cannot. It cannot as the Micro-USB port would not be able to push out enough power, as well as the fact that the battery would drain *very* quickly if this were to happen.
- > Can I access the external USB drive without restrictions as if it was an SD card, or are there any additional restrictions?

  You can access it like you would on your computer, through a file manager. The app you choose may restrict the access, however.

Comment: Regarding the hard drive bit, I have seen reports of some 2.5" external hard drives able to function off however much current the Nexus 7 will supply.

Answer (score 1):

An old question I know, but I have been able to use a Verbatim Store 'n' Go portable HDD with an OTG cable without any power issue. The only disadvantage is that I can't power down the drive before removing it (unlike on PC) so I risk shortening the drive's life. Other than that, it's fine.