# Nexus 10, write access to USB pen drive (update)

Tags: usb-peripherals, samsung-nexus-10

I've found the answer to [this question from November](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34281/what-are-the-limitations-of-usb-on-the-go-on-nexus-tablets), which states that the only way you could read from USB was with the Nexus Media Importer, although I've gotten the impression that that is read only and only for media files.

Time has passed, and I'm wondering if there is now a way to read/write to USB pen drives from the Nexus 10. This is on a company tablet so root access is totally out. Are there any free alternatives to NMI?